# Convert image to progressive JPEG in swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, jpeg, progressive

I need to covert my UIImage to progressive jpeg using swift 3.0.
I have found the following code in swift 2.2:

```
    let sourceImage = UIImage(named: "example.jpg")
let path = (NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as NSString).stringByAppendingPathComponent("progressive.jpg")
let fileUrl = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path as String, isDirectory: true)
let url = CFURLCreateWithString(kCFAllocatorDefault,fileUrl.absoluteString as CFString  , nil)
let destinationRef = CGImageDestinationCreateWithURL(url, kUTTypeJPEG, 1, nil)
let jfifProperties = NSDictionary(dictionary: [kCGImagePropertyJFIFIsProgressive:kCFBooleanTrue])
let properties = NSDictionary(dictionary: [kCGImageDestinationLossyCompressionQuality:0.6,kCGImagePropertyJFIFDictionary:jfifProperties])
CGImageDestinationAddImage(destinationRef!, (sourceImage?.CGImage)!, properties)
CGImageDestinationFinalize(destinationRef!)
```

But it doesn't work in swift 3.0. CGImageDestinationCreateWithURL gives an error.(all the CGImage classes...) Any help? Thanks!

Comment: "I have found the following code". Don't use code you don't understand.

Comment: Thank you for you help. I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A translation to Swift 3 would be similar to this:

```
guard let sourceImage = UIImage(named: "example.jpg") else {
    fatalError("Image could not be loaded")
}

let documentsUrl = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
let targetUrl = documentsUrl.appendingPathComponent("progressive.jpg") as CFURL

let destination = CGImageDestinationCreateWithURL(targetUrl, kUTTypeJPEG, 1, nil)!
let jfifProperties = [kCGImagePropertyJFIFIsProgressive: kCFBooleanTrue] as NSDictionary
let properties = [
    kCGImageDestinationLossyCompressionQuality: 0.6,
    kCGImagePropertyJFIFDictionary: jfifProperties
] as NSDictionary

CGImageDestinationAddImage(destination, sourceImage.cgImage!, properties)
CGImageDestinationFinalize(destination)
```

Don't forget the necessary module imports:

```
import UIKit
import ImageIO
import MobileCoreServices
```

Comment: Thanks! I just figured out that i forgot to import these modules. btw did you understand this code? Does this code convert the "sourceImage" to a progressive one with its data?

Comment: @MarcIbrahim Yes, with 60% compression ratio.